# How to find a record by unique value inside an array in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to locate a record which has the "String to match" in his "affiliates.wallets" array. But for some reason, I'm unable to do it.

I was trying something like:

```js
db.collection.findOne({ "affiliates.wallets": {$in: "[String to match]"}, (err, data) => console.log(err, data)})
```

But it returns `null`. So, I'm asking for help.

Simplified Wallet Schema:

```js
Wallet {
  affiliates: {
    wallets: [String]
  }
}
```

P.S: I'm using `findOne` method because this "String to match" which I'm using to locate the record is unique and it can be located only in one record.

Comment: this seems to work: https://mongoplayground.net/p/CGYgABvHXsm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `$in` operator. You can do it like this:

```js
db.collection.findOne({
  "affiliates.wallets": "String to match", 
}, (err, data) => {
  console.log(err, data)
})
```